# how to transforme .txt files (text corpus) to .arff files

Tags: java, weka

I have tried with simple cli but always give me an empty `.arff` files.
My `.txt` file is a text corpus from ruiters or any other corpus. I have tried with this but not working for me.

```
import java.io.*;
import weka.core.*;

/**
 * Builds an arff dataset from the documents in a given directory.
 * Assumes that the file names for the documents end with ".txt".
 *
 * Usage:<p>
 *
 * TextDirectoryToArff <directory path><p>
 *
 * @author Richard Kirkby (rkirkby at cs.waikato.ac.nz)
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class TextDirectoryToArff {

  public Instances createDataset(String directoryPath) throws Exception {
    FastVector atts = new FastVector(2);
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("filename", (FastVector) null));
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("contents", (FastVector) null));
    Instances data = new Instances("D:\\Esl\\Nouveaudossier\\010101.txt" + directoryPath, atts, 0);

    File dir = new File(directoryPath);
    String[] files = dir.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (files[i].endsWith(".txt")) {
      try {
        double[] newInst = new double[2];
        newInst[0] = (double)data.attribute(0).addStringValue(files[i]);
        File txt = new File(directoryPath + File.separator + files[i]);  
        InputStreamReader is;
        is = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(txt));
        StringBuffer txtStr = new StringBuffer();
        int c;
        while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
          txtStr.append((char)c);
        }
        newInst[1] = (double)data.attribute(1).addStringValue(txtStr.toString());
        data.add(new Instance(1.0, newInst));
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println("failed to convert file: " + directoryPath + File.separator + files[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    return data;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length == 1) {
      TextDirectoryToArff tdta = new TextDirectoryToArff();
      try {
        Instances dataset = tdta.createDataset(args[0]);
        System.out.println(dataset);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("Usage: java TextDirectoryToArff <directory name>");
    }
  }
}
```